# How to ignore security warnings thrown when using pip install to private pypi server using self signed cert

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I have what I believe is a niche scenario.  I have a pypi server running on a Linux server.  Retrieving packages from it using:

`pip install --extra-index-url http://<IP>:8080 MyPackage`

Works as one would expect with the package being downloaded from the private repo.

However since introducing a self signed certificate into the equation (I do not have a domain for this IP) using the following command:

`pip install --cert apache-selfsigned.crt --extra-index-url https://UN:PW@<IP>:443 MyPackage`

I get the following errors (though it does still work as you can see at the bottom):

```
Collecting MyPackage
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /simple/MyPackage/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /simple/MyPackage/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /simple/MyPackage/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /simple/MyPackage/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /simple/MyPackage/
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:860: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
Installing collected packages: MyPackage
Successfully installed MyPackage-0.2.0
```

I use Apache2 to act as a reverse proxy to forward port 443 onto the pypi port.

The certificate is 'valid' but obviously not registered with a CA.  It works fine for encryption and for connecting via a web browser (once I accept the 'risks').  So I know the cert/key are working correctly.

It seems highly inefficient for pip to try 5 times and fail before deciding to go ahead with the unverified certificate, is there something amiss in the cert?  Or is it just that pip's dependencies don't like self signed certs, and will always fail 5 times before admitting its ok.

Comment: Because of `extra-index-url`, `pip` searches on PyPI, and because of `cert`, it uses it to check `pypi.org` host, obviously failing. As a workaround, you can use `--trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org` if you need to use your repo via `extra-index-url`; however, a proper solution IMO would be system wide installing a proper self-signed cert bound to a DN. Also, you don't need `--trusted-host=<IP>` if you're using `--cert`.

Comment: Or you can ignore PyPI completely and install everything from your own index server via `--index-url=<IP>`. The rest depends on the server impl; either you'll need to host all the package dependencies yourself, or use e.g. `devpi` which acts as a PyPI proxy (packages not available locally will be downloaded from PyPI).

Comment: Thank you, the --trusted-host is removed from the question to avoid confusion, I actually discovered this just before I read your message during my 'trial and error' attempts at finding a solution.  I wish I knew of --index-url, this in short is my answer, please do post an answer properly as you have solved this for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `--extra-index-url`, `pip` will still use PyPI along your extra index when searching for a package. Unfortunately, there is no way to specify an "extra-index cert" so when you pass `--cert`, `pip` will use the cert against all index hosts including `pypi.org`. This is why you get the `certificate verify failed` errors. To circumvent this, you can:

- Install the certificate system wide, so you don't have to pass `--cert` at all. The exact steps are OS-dependent, also you'll need additional steps for virtual envs.
- Use `--index-url=<IP> --cert=my.crt` - beware that in that case `pip` will not query PyPI at all, so you will be able to install only packages that are offered by your own index. Decent index servers like `devpi` can act as a proxy to PyPI though, so not so much of an issue.
- Trust the PyPI hosts: `--extra-index-url=<IP> --cert=my.cert --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org` - this will skip the PyPI hosts verification, thus unsafe and should only be a temporary workaround.